# Solr MoreLikeThis not working for multiple shards?

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I have 5 node cluster in SolrCloud, with 2 shards per node,

Solr version:6.3.0

[image]

now when I run mlt query it only returns result per node and doesn't distribute them over all shards/nodes, i.e

http://10.0.1.15:8983/solr/test_ingest/mlt?q=advertising_id%w72w9424620427042&fl=score&fl=advertising_id&mlt.fl=channel_name&mlt.fl=show_name&mlt.fl=language&mlt.mindf=1

gives no results while

http://10.0.1.119:8983/solr/test_ingest/mlt?q=advertising_id%w72w9424620427042&fl=score&fl=advertising_id&mlt.fl=channel_name&mlt.fl=show_name&mlt.fl=language&mlt.mindf=1

gives results,

I have even tried specifying this as param:

shards=10.0.1.84:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard3_replica1,10.0.1.84:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard8_replica1,10.0.1.206:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard2_replica1,10.0.1.206:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard7_replica1,10.0.1.15:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard5_replica1,10.0.1.15:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard10_replica1,10.0.1.207:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard1_replica1,10.0.1.207:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard6_replica1,10.0.1.119:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard9_replica1,10.0.1.119:8983/solr/test_ingest_shard4_replica1

My request handler:

```
 <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
 </requestHandler>
```

How do I configure mlt to run a distributed search?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The More Like This Handler is, as far as I know, single shard only, so it'll only consider the documents available in the local shard.

The [More Like This Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-MoreLikeThisQueryParser) do however mention that it is Solr Cloud-aware, so try using that instead.

> MLTQParser enables retrieving documents that are similar to a given document. It uses Lucene's existing MoreLikeThis logic and also works in SolrCloud mode. The document identifier used here is the unique id value and not the Lucene internal document id. The list of returned documents excludes the queried document.
>
> Find documents like the document with id=1 and using the name field for similarity.
>
> `{!mlt qf=name}1`
>
> Adding more constraints to what qualifies as similar using mintf and mindf.
>
> `{!mlt qf=name mintf=2 mindf=3}1`

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked, although the query times for a single ID is around 15-30 ms, and I need to get mlt for around 1-4 mil ids, what would be best way to do that from java, I have used CloudSolrClient in a ThreadPool.

Comment: If you're spending 30 ms for each lookup and you've got 4m documents, that would be done in 37 hours. So totally doable within a couple of days with what you already have. If you need more capacity, spreading the queries across more replicas should work, at least to allow for more queries in parallel (it won't reduce the query time, but you should be able to run more queries in parallel without any significant slowdown).