# SOLR: More Like This gives uncertain result for same query

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

The mlt handler has been configured like this:

```
 "/mlt":{
          "name":"/mlt",
          "class":"solr.MoreLikeThisHandler",
          "defaults":{
            "df":"en_ss_catchall",
            "mlt.boost":true,
            "mlt.qf":"*",
            "mlt.fl":"*",
            "mlt.mindf":2,
            "mlt.mintf":1,
            "mlt.count":5}
        }
    }
```

When i hit this handler, i get response sometimes and i don't get response sometimes. I don't change my query in-between. Just search repeatedly, and the handler generates uncertain results.

Comment: Are you running SolrCloud with multiple nodes?

Comment: Yes i am..and data is replicated in all.

Comment: So no sharding? The MLT handler is local shard only, so the results would differ based on which shard you'd hit. See [Solr MoreLikeThis not working for multiple shards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390064/solr-morelikethis-not-working-for-multiple-shards) for a work around.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks. I feel this could be the shard issue. But anyways, how can i support multiple shards even if i have to?

Comment: Use the MLT Query Parser as shown in the post I linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr MoreLikeThis not working for multiple shards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390064/solr-morelikethis-not-working-for-multiple-shards)

Comment: @MatsLindh: http://localhost.com:8983/solr/products/mlt?q=id:uae!PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY&fq=countryCode_SOLR_s_:uae&!mlt.match.include=true&{!mlt%20qf=itemType_SOLR_s_}PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY{!mlt%20qf=brand_SOLR_ss_}PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY{!mlt%20fl=itemType_SOLR_s_}PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY{!mlt%20fl=brand_SOLR_ss_}PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY

Comment: Tried MLT Query Parser to tackle with solr cloud, but its not working.

Comment: You can't have multiple localparams in a single parameter, and I can't see it even being added as a parameter. Update your _question_ with details of what you've tried and the results, and be sure to format it properly - it's very hard to make sense of content in the comments.

Comment: Query: http://localhost:8983/solr/products/mlt?q=id:uae!PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY&{!mlt%20fq=countryCode_SOLR_s_:uae}PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY

Comment: This query is supposed to get similar products to the product provided as id, and because my products are sprad across different shards, how do i ensure this get me data every-time i run.

Comment: You're still not giving the mlt-handler as a localparam to a parameter - you can't just include the `{...}` part directly in the string. `q={!mlt ....}id:uae!PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY`. And you'll have to use a field that contain text about the item (the `qf` part of the syntax), i.e. something to use for finding similar items. A single country code won't give much relevancy. In your previous example you use widely different parameter names for the multiple params you give. And yet again, please update your _question_ with new details, do not add them in the comments.

Comment: @MatsLindh This geerates result. mlt?q={!mlt%20qf=%27color_SOLR_en_ss_%20,itemType_SOLR_s_,countryCode_SOLR_s_%27%20mintf=1%20mindf=1}uae!PGAHBTUPQ7WSTWOACY. This gives me result but sometimes uae country comes and sometimes ksa, even if the product with given id is of uae.

Comment: Yes, that's because country (uae) is not the only field considered. Similar does not mean identical. If you want to limit it to the same country, apply a filter with the country (i.e. something like `fq=country:uae`). Not completely sure it'll work as expected with the query parser, but try it.

Comment: @MatsLindh: That's what i already did to filter now separately, which is working with /select handler. With my /mlt results are still fuzzy.

Comment: You don't have to use /mlt when you're using the query parser.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks @MatsLindh. Thanks for your patience and help. Cheers. :)

Comment: @MatsLindh One issue happened.. I fired the query as: http://localhost:8983/solr/products/select?q={!mlt+qf%3D%22brand_SOLR_ss_,ram_SOLR_fs_,itemType_SOLR_s_%22%20mintf%3D1+mindf%3D1}ksa!PMOBJ3SJX4X9APRENT&countryCode=ksa. Getting error: "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Invalid Number: mobile", the ram field is decimal, making the field as string works. What is the problem happening?

Comment: My guess is that MLT doesn't really make sense for numeric fields, only text fields.

Comment: @MatsLindh That's true may be, but we might try to find similar products to a mobile say which has same 8GB ram. Do let me know if you find any reference, or the only way i see is to exclude the numeric fields or store them as strings too.